# Saving custom attribute to Order model in Spree eCommerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have added a custom field in my spree_orders table (let's call it `custom_attribute`).

I have added `Spree::PermittedAttributes.checkout_attributes << [:custom_attribute]` to my spree.rb initializer.

In my checkout process I have a custom form with the following code (html formatting has been removed):

```
<%= form_for @order do |alt_form| %>
      <%= alt_form.label :custom_attribute, "Custom Attribute" %><span class="required">*</span><br />
      <%= alt_form.text_field :custom_attribute, :class => 'form-control required', maxlength: 11 %>
<% end %>
```

This form successfully submits the field in the post request (full dump below) to http://localhost:3000/checkout/update/address as `order[custom_attribute] xyz`, however, the information is not saved to the model.

```
_method=patch
_method=patch
authenticity_token=Y+ATRotWKfI57f+b0/YGwIw9Bg6mADHBDmeEOHYzLPnB6Vbydya4ITDTopcX65EG+TiL7bwyJKQPpBU9bQTaUg==
authenticity_token=Y+ATRotWKfI57f+b0/YGwIw9Bg6mADHBDmeEOHYzLPnB6Vbydya4ITDTopcX65EG+TiL7bwyJKQPpBU9bQTaUg==
commit=Save and Continue
order[bill_address_attributes][address1]=123 Test
order[bill_address_attributes][address2]=
order[bill_address_attributes][city]=Test
order[bill_address_attributes][country_id]=232
order[bill_address_attributes][firstname]=Test
order[bill_address_attributes][id]=3
order[bill_address_attributes][lastname]=Test
order[bill_address_attributes][phone]=555555555
order[bill_address_attributes][state_id]=3535
order[bill_address_attributes][zipcode]=30024
order[email]=spree@example.com
order[custom_attribute]=2414
order[state_lock_version]=32
utf8=✓
utf8=✓
```

**I've inserted @order.inspect on the following (payment) page to can see at that point that @order.custom_attribute is still nil.**

Does anyone have any idea about what I need to do in order to get the `custom_attribute` value sent in the post request saved to the model with the other attributes sent?

-------------------edit-------------------

Default spree permitted attributes are defined here https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/3-0-stable/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/strong_parameters.rb and are added on by the `strong_paramaters` helper here (don't have the rep to post a third link):

```
module Spree
  module Core
    module ControllerHelpers
      module StrongParameters
        def permitted_attributes
          Spree::PermittedAttributes
        end

        delegate *Spree::PermittedAttributes::ATTRIBUTES,
                 to: :permitted_attributes,
                 prefix: :permitted

        def permitted_payment_attributes
          permitted_attributes.payment_attributes + [
            source_attributes: permitted_source_attributes
          ]
        end

        def permitted_checkout_attributes
          permitted_attributes.checkout_attributes + [
            bill_address_attributes: permitted_address_attributes,
            ship_address_attributes: permitted_address_attributes,
            payments_attributes: permitted_payment_attributes,
            shipments_attributes: permitted_shipment_attributes
          ]
        end

        def permitted_order_attributes
          permitted_checkout_attributes + [
            line_items_attributes: permitted_line_item_attributes
          ]
        end

        def permitted_product_attributes
          permitted_attributes.product_attributes + [
            product_properties_attributes: permitted_product_properties_attributes
          ]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which can be at found `spree/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/strong_parameters.rb` in the spree github repo.

-------------------final edit-------------------
If anyone finds this in the future and is trying to troubleshoot a similar issue, my code above is actually correct; I had (stupidly) placed it in an `if Rails.env.production?` block.

Comment: Can you add the controller code where the attributes would be assigned?

Comment: @eirkir it's a bit complicated as it's in the spree codebase but I'll go ahead and edit in what I think (could be wrong)  you're asking for.

Comment: How did you added your custom_attribute? Can you explain?
I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an example, maybe you can translate it into your code.

---

**OPTIONAL**

Imagine that I have a custom action, called `"custom"` on my `users` controller, defined this way in my routes:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'custom'
    post 'custom'
  end
end
```

This way I can call it by using **custom_users_path**.

Next, I want a form that submits to that function, to do that you need to specify an **additional parameter in your form_for called :url**, in this example I call it using `custom_users_path`, once I submit the form, It will run my custom action.

**form_for would look like this:**

```
<%= form_for :user, :url  => custom_users_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :random %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

---

Then, I want to be able to access some `:random parameter` in my users controller. Let's suppose that I have a text_field which I want store the value on my `:random parameter` (see above). First, you need to permit that parameter to be accessible in your controller, in this example, in users controller. This way:

```
params.require(:user).permit(YOUR PARAMETER HERE, {:random => []})
```

So, every time I submit the form, I can access the `:submit parameter` value, by doing this `params["controller-name"]["parameter-name"]`, translated into this example, would look like:

```
params["user"]["random"]
```

You can then convert it into string using to_s if you want.

**Output** (Supposing that I wrote "444" on my text_field):

```
444
```

I hope this helps you.